# Using HBase table Snapshot in Oozie Workflow

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce, hbase, oozie, hadoop2

I am trying to run a MapReduce job on oozie which takes HBase table snapshot as its input. Currently I am able to do it (not using oozie workflow) using `org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.TableMapReduceUtil` which provides me with a method `initTableSnapshotMapperJob()`.

Is there a similar option in oozie, where I can specify HBase SNAPSHOT as input to my map reduce job. If not what are the other options?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Uber jar for this. Oozie allows to schedule uber jars directly without configuration of Mapper and Reducer:

```
<action name="mr-node">
    <map-reduce>
        <job-tracker>${jobTracker}</job-tracker>
        <name-node>${nameNode}</name-node>
        <configuration>
            <property>
                <name>oozie.mapreduce.uber.jar</name>
                <value>${nameNode}/user/${wf:user()}/my-uber-jar.jar</value>
            </property>
        </configuration>
    </map-reduce>
    <ok to="end"/>
    <error to="fail"/>
</action>
```

Before doing this make sure your **oozie.action.mapreduce.uber.jar.enable** property is set to true in **oozie-site.xml**

Answer (score 0):

I dont think you can do that with oozie MapReduce Action. Maybe, you can use a Java Action. But, with Java Action you will need to write a driver for your MapReduce job.  
As per my experience with Oozie, MapReduce action has a lot of limitations apart from basic stuff. For example: Oozie does not supports ChainMapper and ChainReducer.